# What frameworks should you use to ensure secure client server infrastructure architecture

Tags: c#, security, frameworks, client-server

I would like to develop a client-server application and would like to know what the best frameworks are to ensure security.

So far I have got the following:

- Microsoft.Net c# 4.5
- WPF

Other than that I am unsure what else I should/could be using? I am not sure WPF is the right thing to be using, is there a RESTful framework I should use instead, or maybe entity framework?

Also is there any obvious frameworks which will be/should be using which I haven't mentioned?

I would like to use either Azure or AWS to host my servers etc, are there any specific frameworks for these which I will need?

Are there any security specific frameworks I should be using?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Security is a huge subject but the first few basic things to consider are.

1. Use HTTPS
2. Implement security token for your service
3. Prevent cross site scripting
4. Prevent script injections

you may find a simple [code sample here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/martinkearn/2015/03/25/securing-and-securely-calling-web-api-and-authorize/)